# How do I manage the limits of this double integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

I haven't studied multiple integrals yet, but when I look at the integration by parts formula, I see that there is an integral of an integral.  If the integration being done has limits, I'm not sure how they're managed.  Here is what I have:

So the by parts formula is
$\int f(x)g'(x)dx = f(x)g(x)-\int f'(x)g(x)dx$

If I have $g'(x)$, then I need $g(x)$.

My question is this: if I'm solving with limits, do I apply limits to $\int g'(x)dx$ also?

In other words, do I do this

$\int_a^b xe^{6x}dx = x \cdot |\frac{1}{6}e^{6x}|_a^b - \int_a^b1\cdot \frac{1}{6}e^{6x}dx$

or this

$\int_a^b xe^{6x}dx = x \cdot |\frac{1}{6}e^{6x}|_a^b - \int_a^b1\cdot |\frac{1}{6}e^{6x}|_a^bdx$

?

Comment: The correct formula is $[x(1/6)e^{6x}]|_a^b -\int_a^b e^{6x}dx$.  In the IPB formula $V=g(x)$ is a specific antiderivative, not a definite integral. The general rule would be $\int_a^b f(x)g'(x)\, dx=[f(x)g(x) ]|_a^b - \int _a^b g(x)f'(x) \,dx$.

Comment: This is not a double integral. An example of a double integral is $\int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d}f(x,y)dxdy$.

Comment: @AméricoTavares Ah, ok.  Thanks.

Comment: @DavidMitra why is x included in the limits for the integral of $e^{6x}$?  Why isn't it $x[(1/6)e^{6x}]|_a^b$?...never mind I figured it out :)  Thanks!

Comment: @Korgan Because the IPB formula says an antiderivative of $fg'$ is $fg-\int gf'$. So, to evaluate a definite integral $\int_a^b f(x)g'(x)\,dx$: You first find an antiderivative of the integrand. One is, by the IPB formula, $F (x) =f(x)g(x)-\int g(x)f'(x)\, dx$. Then, you plug in the limits and take the difference.  The result of this is equivalent to what the formula  I have above gives.

Comment: @David: Do you mean "IBP"? If not, what does "IPB" stand for?

Comment: @joriki, yes.. Seems I'm dyslexic today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes like this:

$\int_a^b xe^{6x}dx = (x \cdot \frac{1}{6}e^{6x})|_a^b - \int_a^b(1\cdot \frac{1}{6}e^{6x})dx$

$f(x) g(x)$ is evaluated from $a$ to $b$ and so is the integral $\int^b_a [f'(x) g(x)] dx$